# Albino pedigree question

Tags: genetics, homework

`https://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/playquiz/?title=pedigrees-quiz` is a link to the website containing this question.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you came up with your table, but I encourage you to start over.

Among other things it appears to me that you've made an unwarranted assumption about the unaffected sister's genotype.

1. I suggest you start by making a Punnett square for the albino's parents and think about what that means for unaffected sister.
2. Next think about what must be true for the unaffected sister to have an albino child with the unrelated non-albino man.

   • Once, you've calculated the probability of that situation you're one step away from your answer.
3. Finally, given the situation in (2) what is the probability that the couple will have an albino child?